# "Premium SSL" vs "Stanard SSL" certificates - Any reason why I would want a "Premium SSL"?

Tags: encryption, tls, certificates, web-hosting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are the advantages of EV Certificate?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/15865/what-are-the-advantages-of-ev-certificate)

besides the green URL bar and free security scan and whatnot.

Our website does NOT accept any personal info other than email address and passwords.
So no banking compliance needed.

But our company business revolves around subscribers logging on for information they paid for.., (xls docs, etc).

Does anyone know of any other compliance reasons why anyone really needs a Premium SSL cert instead of the basic SSL package?  both are '40-bit minimum to 256-bit SSL encryption'.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From a security perspective, you don't get any additional capabilities from the Premium vs the Standard as long as the key lengths are the same.  The difference is simply the level of validation that the CA performs and thus gives the end user more confidence in your site being legit.

Comment: True.  Essentially, the CA super-double-triple checks that you are the company you claim to be, and that you own the domain you claim to own.  They already do this for standard certs, but they /really/ do it for premium/EV certs.

Answer (score 5):

You want the premium SSL certificate *exactly* because of the green bar. This is all about making the putative customer feel safe and comfy. Remember that, by definition, your certificate is not for you; this is an object which you need to convince *other people* that you are who you claim to be.

Comment: We don't care much about the 'green bar'.  It really has no use and our website login access is not publicly accessible.

Comment: It's just about the PR. Really. We went through it for our website and some of the other developers had to be convinced it was *just* about looking "more" secure.

Comment: I think you are confusing Premium SSL with EV SSL, Premium certificates do not have the green bar.