# Grey vs Green padlock in address bar - technical difference

Tags: tls, certificates, certificate-authority

What is a technical difference between "grey padlock" and "green padlock" in URL bar in browsers?

[image]

As an example we can take:

- Green padlock: [Bank of America](https://www.bankofamerica.com/)
- Grey padlock: [Google Search](https://www.google.pl/search?q=cat)

Both of them are signed by proper CAs.

So my questions are:

- What is a technical difference?
- How does it impact my browsingsecurity?
- Are there some best practises what shouldn't be done on pages with "grey padlock"?

Comment: What OS and browser are you using? Have you looked at other browsers to see if there's commonality?

Comment: I don't think OS or browser does impact on differences in SSL certificates.

Comment: Just to be clear: W7/FF.26

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Firefox, a grey padlock indicates that the site in question does not use an EV certificate. Sites using EV certificates shows up as a green padlock.

There is mostly no practical difference between the two types of certificates. Both are equally secure from a technical POV. For a more thorough answer about EV certificates, see [What are the advantages of EV Certificate?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/15865/what-are-the-advantages-of-ev-certificate)