# Why doesn't the most powerful/powerful sites on the internet use Extended Validation SSL certificates?

Tags: tls, facebook, twitter

Why does some of the biggest internet companies not use an Extended Validated certificate which makes the address bar would be green and more secure?

I have noticed that Facebook, Google, Amazon the biggest companies I could think of that holds alot of sensitive information does not use EV.

**Twitter uses EV**, most of the recognized clothing brands like **Victoria Secrets does use EV.**

---

> The best way I can put this question is in this way:
>
> **Why does Twitter use Extended Validated SSL certificate whereas Facebook doesn't**

*This is a reasonable question because both of these are social networking sites*

Comment: http://security.stackexchange.com/a/15871/49075 ​ ​