# Why not buy cheap SSL certificates?

Tags: encryption, tls, certificates, certificate-authority

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there any technical security reason not to buy the cheapest SSL certificate you can find?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/18666/is-there-any-technical-security-reason-not-to-buy-the-cheapest-ssl-certificate-y)

The [comparison](http://www.godaddy.com/ssl/ssl-certificates.aspx) in Godaddy's website, makes it clear: they're just cheaper than others. Frankly I have used both Verisign and godaddy. Well, the price difference is huge. Both use 256-bit encryption, provide prompt service and work with major browsers.

Is there any hidden difference that make people pay more for Verisign or other providers?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Is there any technical security reason not to buy the cheapest SSL certificate you can find?](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/18666/5501)