# Is it possible for a successful domain hijacker to fraudulently use the certificate issued to the real owner of the domain name?

Tags: certificates

In other words, while visiting `https://www.mybank.com`, for example, can I always trust the site as long as I click the padlock in the address bar of my browser and find no problem with the certificate?

Answer (score 4):

No, you can't trust it. It is possible that:

1. [The real site has suffered a compromise of its private key](https://twitter.com/elie/status/540579904056995842)
2. [One of the many certificate authorities whose root certificates are in your browser has suffered a compromise of its signing key](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DigiNotar)
3. [One of the certificate authorities is not following procedures correctly and is issuing certificates that it shouldn't be](https://nakedsecurity.sophos.com/2013/01/08/the-turktrust-ssl-certificate-fiasco-what-happened-and-what-happens-next/)
4. [There's a bug in the browser or a certificate authority's software that allows an attacker to get a certificate issued that the browser trusts](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ibF36Yyeehw)
5. [A government agency has got its own root certificate included in your browser as a trusted certificate authority](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/71171/is-there-anything-preventing-the-nsa-from-becoming-a-root-ca)
6. [There's a zero-day exploit of the TLS protocol](http://heartbleed.com)

([Certificate pinning](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Certificate_and_Public_Key_Pinning) is a mitigation for numbers 2, 3, 4 & 5, but requires more knowledge and experience from the user, and is not yet widely implemented, although Chrome has some support for it.)

Comment: or 6b) SSL/TLS is misconfigured for the site and use or allow old insecure protocols or cipher suites to be used. By far the most common problem...