# Difference between free ssl and non-free ssl?

Tags: encryption, tls

I am making a choice between StartSSL and positiveSSL($4.99/yr). I want to know the difference between them. As I know, SSL is used to encrypted the connection between client and server so that data transferred(cookie) will not be under 'man-in-the-middle' attack.

Doing some searches on StartSSL, I found a website said 'They don't do any verification beyond email address and the domain name, so they aren't good for ecommerce.' What does this mean? Does StartSSL encrypt the data transfered? If no, can you tell me which type of SSL will encrypt data in the connection?

I just want the post data and cookie will be encrypted in https request.

Comment: I have read that question. They said the free ssl and non-free ssl are technically same. However, I am just confused by comments from other website. Here, I just want to understand whether free ssl encrypts data in the connection.

Comment: You might have read the question, but have you read its answers too? They answer your question straight on. What the site you quote discusses is [certificate validation by a Certificate Authority (CA)](http://security.stackexchange.com/a/36170/20074).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both free and non-free SSL will encrypt your connection, it's not because you pay less that it offers any less "encryption" features.

Answer (score 0):

Free [SSL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Sockets_Layer) and Non-Free SSL both are cryptographic protocols which are designed to provide communication security over the Internet.

Once you can choose Free SSL - You spend no cost with a limited period.

You can choose non-free (Buy SSL) - You can spend money and upgrade after expire your SSL package.

In my suggestion Use Free SSL with limited period, This SSL Certificate is fine, then upgrade SSL Certificate for same company. otherwise you changed another one SSL manufacture...