# How to see absolute difference between DV and OV certificates?

Tags: certificates

I know that browsers show no difference to the user between OV and DV certificates, but what is a sure way to find out if a certificate IS or ISNT an OV certificate?

Also, are there any technical differences in the cert?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I know that browsers show no difference to the user between OV and DV certificates, but what is a sure way to find out if a certificate IS or ISNT an OV certificate?
>
> Also, are there any technical differences in the cert?

Another answer partly answers your question: [How does an end user differentiate between OV and DV certificates?](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/35076/52333)

> DV certificate contains no identifying information in the organization name field. Typically, this value just re-states the domain name or simply says "Persona Not Validated".

The organization name field is not part of a domain validated certificate.

Additionally, the policy identifier is different for DV and OV:

- Domain Validated: 2.23.140.1.2.1
- Organization Validated: 2.23.140.1.2.2

You can find this field in Extensions > Certificate Policies.