# YubiKey or Google authenticator?

Tags: passwords, password-management, multi-factor

I'm using [lastpass](https://lastpass.com/) and I would like to implement a 2FA in my account, but I don't know which one is the most secure, a software authenticator such as [google authenticator](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.authenticator2&hl=pt_BR) or an USB device as [Yubikey](https://www.yubico.com/).

Since there isn't any password manager which has 3FA, I'm a little confused which one is the most secure.

Thanks

Answer (score 13):

Google Authenticator is *pretty* secure. Certainly better than nothing, and in fact better than most of the options out there.

Yubico OTP devices are *slightly better*, because it's more difficult to extract the keys out of a Yubico device than a cell phone.

That said, neither is perfect because both are OTP-based and therefore both can be phished. This is a vulnerability that is today being actively exploited by groups like the Syrian Electronic Army, and is the cause for a number of high-profile breaches.

[There is a solution](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/71704/2264) which *can't* be phished, but as of this writing, [LastPass doesn't support it](https://lastpass.com/support.php?cmd=showfaq&id=8126). So while I still recommend using your Yubikey or Authenticator code as a second factor, I would caution you to not let your guard down in its use, because you're still vulnerable to phishing.

Comment: You can also use the yubikey authenticator to get 3FA. It is a google authenticator clone which requires your yubikey to unlock.