# fake website used for phishing purposes

Tags: phishing

Our real web site is `www.abc.com`. Recently Intel notified us of another web site `www.fake.com` having some parts of the site appearing the same as our real site. This is obviously a phishing site.

Not much damage has been done and I don't think our users are stupid enough to recognize `www.fake.com` as our real site and try to access it. However, I would like to know what are the mitigation measures we could take.

I reckon sending our users an email or a company circular to warn them that we have only one real site is a must. What else can we do to prevent?

Comment: This is more a legal issue than a security one. The best way to prevent the phishing of login credentials is by using U2F

Comment: Blocking the fake domain and its IP address on the corporate proxy/network would be a start, and for a legal solution I guess you could claim copyright infringement since the fake site copies your real one.

Comment: contact the hosting company and report the site

Comment: @NeilMcGuigan - Do you feel that any 2FA would be sufficient or that U2F provides better security than other 2FA solutions?

Comment: @NeilSmithline U2F prevents phishing by only "connecting" to known domains that you have previously registered with. Other 2FA's won't help here.

Comment: Thanks @NeilMcGuigan - I'll go reread the U2F documentation. I guess I missed something.

Comment: @NeilSmithline A googler outlines some info here: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/71316/how-secure-are-the-fido-u2f-tokens

Comment: Thanks for the info @NeilMcGuigan. U2F does seem better at preventing phishing than other 2FA. I found this helpful too https://developers.yubico.com/U2F/Protocol_details/Overview.html

Comment: I don't think this strictly is a duplicate, since the current question "What can be done?" has a broader scope than "Where to report?", but I think the following question is still very relevant: [Where to report malicious URLs, phishing, and malicious web sites?](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/1728/32746)

Answer (score 1):

I know that RSA offers services that will, among other things, take down phishing sites. More information can be found [here](http://www.emc.com/security/rsa-fraud-prevention/rsa-fraudaction.htm).

I have experience with them and I must say, whenever we request a take down on a phishing site, their response is quite fast.

Unfortunately, I have no idea regarding costs etc.