# Why do X.509 certificates have "Key Usage" attribute?

Tags: certificates, public-key-infrastructure, x.509

I can find their values and all details in the RFC, but I cannot find why it was decided to have this attribute in certificates, instead of leaving them to be multipurposes.

Is there a reasoning behind this choice (key length?) or is it strictly business related, as they are priced very differently?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Strictly speaking, a key *should not* be "multipurpose". Distinct key usages call for incompatible [key life cycles](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/8559/digital-certificate-deployment-using-two-certs-for-each-user/8563#8563). The `Key Usage` extension is a formalism of this fact.

For instance, keys which are used for signatures and authentication could be lost with relatively low consequences: if your smart card is destroyed, you can no longer sign, but no data is lost; you just need to be issued a new smart card (this is inconvenient, but no security breach occurred). But you do not want people to begin to encrypt data with that signature-only public key, because in that case you need to make backups of the key, to avoid data loss upon key loss -- the smart card will strongly oppose to backups, by construction. The `Key Usage` extension documents the idea that a signature key is to be used for signatures only because it won't be backupped. Conversely, an encryption key will normally be escrowed somewhere, and thus you *do not want* people to consider it as binding if it is used for signatures: this would allow whoever has access to the escrow/backup system to sign "in your name". There again, the `Key Usage` extension protects against that.

Comment: Makes sense, thanks. As for the pricing difference, is it because of special procedures on the issuer's side, or is it simply business?

Comment: A typical CA has very high fixed costs, and very low per-certificate costs. The price the CA will make you pay is more correlated with what you will accept to pay than with what issuance really entails; as you say, it is "simply business".