# Is using the same RSA key pair for both (signing and encryption) & (signing and encryption) a bad idea?

Tags: cryptography

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why should one not use the same asymmetric key for encryption as they do for signing?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/1806/why-should-one-not-use-the-same-asymmetric-key-for-encryption-as-they-do-for-sig)

I'm new to IT Security.  I still can't figure out why using the same RSA key pair for both (signing and encryption) & (signing and encryption) is a bad idea?

Most people talk about why we should not use same key pair for signing and encryption, but what about signing and decryption?

Comment: Can you reread your question? Your sentences look a bit mangled.

Comment: @CodeInChaos Yes, I wasn't sure what to make of those, so I left them as is for the OP

Answer (score 0):

There's no technical or cryptography-based reason why you wouldn't want to use the same key for both. The only reasons why are:

- it limits the exposure of your keys -- i.e. you don't have to have the same key available to the people who perform what may be separate tasks
- ancillary legal reasons -- there might be legal requirements around electronic signatures in your country
- damage control in the case of compromise -- i.e. if your private key gets out, then the less that key is useful for the fewer problems it will cause